# Specialty pricing not displaying on product page (view.phtml)

Tags: magento-1.8

I cannot seem to get the special price and the regular price with a strike through to display on the product page.  It displays everywhere else on the site, just except view.phtml.  I have gone through every forum I could find and tried all the solutions.  It is not theme based, as I tested another theme.  I did notice this javascript call in source code of the page which seems to give a clue.

```
    var optionsPrice = new Product.OptionsPrice({"productId":"70","priceFormat":{"pattern":"$%s","precision":2,"requiredPrecision":2,"decimalSymbol":".","groupSymbol":",","groupLength":3,"integerRequired":1},"includeTax":"false","showIncludeTax":false,"showBothPrices":false,"productPrice":1942.5,"productOldPrice":1942.5,"priceInclTax":1942.5,"priceExclTax":1942.5,"skipCalculate":1,"defaultTax":0,"currentTax":0,"idSuffix":"_clone","oldPlusDisposition":0,"plusDisposition":0,"plusDispositionTax":0,"oldMinusDisposition":0,"minusDisposition":0,"tierPrices":[],"tierPricesInclTax":[]});
```

I set all the attributes to the correct settings, made sure price.phtml is correct, cleared cache and emptied var cache to make sure that is not the issue.  Please let me know if anyone has run into an issue like this before or if there is any other info you need.  The site is currently blocked as it is client dev site, but I could add you IP to take a look.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Go to Promotions > Catalog Price Rule > YOUR RULE > Actions > Enable Discount to Subproducts > YES >set the discount exactly the same as you did above it.

Answer (score 0):

In Admin Panel `Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attributes`

In grid Search `special_price`  than in `Frontend properties`

**Visible on Product View Page on Front-end** set as Yes